# Pygame image animation loop not properly looping

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.6

I have a small animation loop that cycles through images quickly. The goal is to make this constant and fluid, but I seem to be running in to an issue where the images show for a second and stay on the first frame.

The following code is from the entire player class with the animation:

```
class Ship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    change_x = 0

    delay = 0
    frame = 1

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = PlayerShip0.convert_alpha()

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = SCREEN_X / 2 - 100
        self.rect.y = SCREEN_Y - 40

    def move(self, speed):
        self.change_x = speed

    def stop(self):
        self.change_x = 0

    def update(self, screen):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        if self.rect.x < 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
        elif self.rect.right > SCREEN_X:
            self.rect.x -= 3

        self.delay += 1
        if self.delay >= 50:
            if self.frame == 1:
                self.image = PlayerShip0.convert_alpha()
                self.frame = 2
                self.delay = 1
            if self.frame == 2:
                self.image = PlayerShip1.convert_alpha()
                self.frame = 3
                self.delay = 1
            if self.frame == 3:
                self.image = PlayerShip2.convert_alpha()
                self.frame = 1
                self.delay = 1

        print(self.frame)

        screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
        if self.frame == 1:
            self.image = PlayerShip0.convert_alpha()
            self.frame = 2
            self.delay = 1
        if self.frame == 2:
            self.image = PlayerShip1.convert_alpha()
            self.frame = 3
            self.delay = 1
        if self.frame == 3:
            self.image = PlayerShip2.convert_alpha()
            self.frame = 1
            self.delay = 1
```

use

```
        if self.frame == 1:
            self.image = PlayerShip0.convert_alpha()
            self.frame = 2
            self.delay = 1
        elif self.frame == 2:
            self.image = PlayerShip1.convert_alpha()
            self.frame = 3
            self.delay = 1
        elif self.frame == 3:
            self.image = PlayerShip2.convert_alpha()
            self.frame = 1
            self.delay = 1
```

Otherwise, you set `self.frame` to `2` in the first `if` block, and the second `if` block will set it to `3` right away, making the condition for the third `if` block truthy, and so on.